# Selecting one value and not the other

Tags: sql, database

TABLE test:

```
id     cd
1      P
2      P
2      S
3      S
```

I want to write a query which would select only the row which has `cd = 'S'` and not the one which has `cd = 'S' and cd = 'P'`.

I would be using `cd` in `WHERE` clause.

So, the query in this scenario would return only id number 3.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT *
FROM <TABLE> 
WHERE CD='S' AND ID NOT IN(SELECT ID FROM <TABLE> WHERE CD='P')
```

Comment: Thanks. I devised a version with NOT EXISTS as well which is faster but your answer helped me.

SELECT *

FROM <TABLE> T

WHERE cd = 'S'

AND NOT EXISTS (

    SELECT 1

    FROM <TABLE>

    WHERE CD = 'P'

    AND id = T.id

);

Answer (score 0):

You can try with:

```
SELECT * FROM test T WHERE cd = 'S' AND 0=(
    SELECT COUNT(*) FROM test B WHERE B.cd = 'P' AND B.id = T.id
)
```

Alternatively you can use JOIN:

```
SELECT * FROM test A LEFT JOIN test B ON
    A.id = B.id AND
    B.cd = 'P'
WHERE B.cd IS NULL AND A.cd = 'S';
```